# Devise: undefined method `params_authenticatable?' for User:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, warden

I am using devise for authentication in my rails app.

I keep getting different errors like "undefined method XXXX for User:class". 
Looking for some help to setup devise correctly.

I have the module database_authenticable setup for Users and I hit the error:

```
undefined method `params_authenticatable?' for User:Class
```

Its comming from the following devise code in lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb

```
  def params_authenticatable?
     mapping.to.params_authenticatable?(authenticatable_name) 
  end
```

Here are my devise settings:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable , :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:linkedin]
.
.

end

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Mu authentication requirements are straightforward and I want to use Linkedin authentication and eventually allowing other omni auths as well.

I am wondering if I should use socery or something else for simple authentication

Thanks !

I am using Rails4.0

Comment: a full error stacktrace is always helpful.

Comment: It's probably something quite trivial you've done (or not done) in another part of the app - posting a full stacktrace will give us more more to go from :)

Comment: sorry for the delay. I upgraded to rails4 and am facing some issues with setting up postgres and running migrations. Will post a stacktrace soon once I get the app working :)